# Change to AsTableServiceQuery() in Client Storage Library 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When using the `TableServiceContext` to query Azure Table Storage I would perform a query like this:

```
var entities = context.CreateQuery<TEntity>(TableName)
                      .AsTableServiceQuery()
                      .Where(condition);
```

But this doesn't compile in the new Client Storage Library 2.0:

> No overload for method 'AsTableServiceQuery' takes 0 arguments.

The only method available is `AsTableServiceQuery(TableServiceContext context);`

This means I would need to have the following:

```
var entities = context.CreateQuery<TEntity>(TableName)
                      .AsTableServiceQuery(context)
                      .Where(condition);
```

I am supplying the context twice.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way IQueryProvider works is that each Linq extension actually modifies the Expression tree and passes it into the provider itself via CreateQuery.

(See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryprovider.aspx)

Since the implementation you are referring to is WCF Data Services the exposed provider creates a DataServiceQuery rather than a TableServiceQuery, essentially stripping it of the Azure specific wrapper. Unfortunately DataServiceQuery does not expose its associated context, which is required for some features and certain reliability checks. Therefore, the final solution requires this last method accept the context again to ensure that the query is correctly wrapped and associated to the context it was created from.

Please note, that the DataServiceQuery does not support continuations, as such when querying against Azure Tables you should always be using the AsTableServiceQuery(ctx) extension to ensure this wrapping is performed.

I would also encourage you to look at the new Table Service Layer introduced in the .Table namespace as it provides for additional flexibility, dramatic performance gains, and avoids these complexities. Note, the TSL does not currently expose an IQueryProvider.

Hope this helps,

Joe

Comment: Great answer!  I would use the new Table Service Layer but it doesn't use the IQueryProvider.  [I asked a question about this here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097902/storage-client-library-2-0-why-is-the-api-not-as-intuitive-to-use-as-1-7)